# (Java) How do you check a string for two or more digit integers using .matches()?

Tags: java, integer, mapping, double

The objective of this program is to return the atomic mass from a given formula (as a String), using a CSV file that contains elements and their atomic masses.

My code for this particular problem is this:

```
    double mass = 0.0;

    Map<String, Double> perTableMap = fileReader(periodicTable);

    Map<String, Integer> atomMap = getAtoms(formula);

    for (Map.Entry<String, Double> periEntry : perTableMap.entrySet()) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> atomEntry : atomMap.entrySet()) {
            if (atomEntry.getKey().equals(periEntry.getKey())) {
                mass += periEntry.getValue() * atomEntry.getValue();
            }
        }
    }

    return mass;
```

I have another method "fileReader" that takes the data from the mile and returns a map with the elements as the key and the mass as the value, this works fine.

This code also works well for "formulas" that have a single digit number of atoms, like "OCS", "C4H4AsH", and "Fe2O3".

However, when the amount of atoms is a 2 or more digit number, it is only reading the first digit of that number.
For example: with "RuSH2112", it is supposed to be Ru*1 + S*1 + H*2112, but instead the output is Ru*1 + S*1 + H*2.

I believe there is something wrong in my method "getAtoms" where it says "!!! HERE !!!", here is the code for that:

```
public static Map<String, Integer> getAtoms(String formula) {

    // LinkedHashMap stores in insertion order
    Map<String, Integer> newMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < formula.length(); i++) {
        int count = 0;

        // convert string to char
        char c = formula.charAt(i);

        // convert char to string
        String a = String.valueOf(c);

        // check formula for upper case values
        if (a.matches("[A-Z]")) {

            for (int j = i + 1; j < formula.length(); j++) {
                char d = formula.charAt(j);
                String b = String.valueOf(d);

                // check formula for lower case values
                if (b.matches("[a-z]")) {
                    a += b;
                    if (newMap.get(a) == null)
                        newMap.put(a, 1);
                    else
                        newMap.put(a, newMap.get(a) + 1);
                    count = 1;
                }

                // check formula for integer values (the end of each molecule)

                // !!! HERE !!!
                else if (b.matches("[\\d]")) {
                    int k = Integer.parseInt(b);
                    newMap.put(a, k);
                    count = 1;
                }

                else {
                    i = j - 1;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // put values into a map
            if (count == 0) {
                if (newMap.get(a) == null)
                    newMap.put(a, 1);
                else
                    newMap.put(a, newMap.get(a) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return newMap;
}
```

Is there another way to say .matches("[\d]")) because I think that only uses one digit numbers?

Comment: `"RuSH2112", it is supposed to be Ru1 + S1 + H2112"` - if you need a regex that matches one or more digit use \\d+

Comment: The *whole code* inside the condition `if (count == 0)` could be substituted with `newMap.merge(a, 1, Integer::sum);`.

Comment: I tried that and it was the same output, do you see any other sort of error where it could cause this problem? using \\d+ still just read it as H2

Comment: Shure that it cant resolve the problem, I've just noticed that you are checking a *single-letter* string, obviously, it cant contain more than one digit.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko the \\d+ didn't change anything and replacing the stuff in the count condition made things worse. Anything else? lol

Comment: You have to split the formula

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko that function splits the formula into a map that looks with the key being the element "H' and the value being the amount of atoms "2", and it does that for the whole formula so isn't it already split up?

Comment: So the desired result for the input `"RuSH2112"` is `Ru=1, S=1, H=2112`?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko yes exactly, that's all I need to be fixed and then my formula will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reimplemented your method `getAtom()`. The main change that has been done to it is that instead of processing a *formula* character by character it splits the *formula* into chunks that represent either uppercase letters, combinations of an uppercase and a lowercase letter, or number.

That's the code for it:

```
String[] elementsAndIndices = formula.split("(?<=\\p{Lower})(?=\\p{Upper})|(?<=\\p{Upper})(?=\\p{Upper})|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");
```

Let's examine what's going on here:

- **\d** - a digit: [0-9];
- **\D** - a non-digit: [^0-9];
- **\p{Lower}** - a lower-case alphabetic character: [a-z];
- **\p{Upper}** - an upper-case alphabetic character:[A-Z];
- **\p{Alpha}** - an alphabetic character:[\p{Lower}\p{Upper}];

Special constructs that start with a *question mark* are called **lookbehind** (`?<=\\p{Lower}`) and **lookahead** (`?=\\p{Upper}`). Both match a *zero-length string* that allows to split the *formula* in a manner that I described above without losing any symbol (you can read more about them [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)).

Meanings of lookbehind and lookbehind combinations that are used to split the formula:

- (?<=\p{Lower})(?=\p{Upper}) - matches a zero-length string between a lower-case character `\p{Lower}` and an upper-case character `\p{Upper}`;
- (?<=\p{Upper})(?=\p{Upper}) - matches a zero-length string on the border between two upper-case characters `\p{Upper}`;
- (?<=\D)(?=\d) - matches a zero-length string between a non-digit `\D` and a digit `\d`;
- (?<=\d)(?=\D) - matches a zero-length string between a digit `\d` and a non-digit `\D`.

Method [**merge()**](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) is used to update the map. It takes three arguments: key, value and remapping function. If the given key is *absent* (or this key is associated with **null** value) then this key will be associated with the *given value*. The remapping function, which is used to merge two values will be *evaluated only* if the provided key is already present and the value for it is *not null*.

```
elements.merge(elementsAndIndices[i], 1, Integer::sum);
```

The line of code shown above associates value `1` with a key `elementsAndIndices[i]` if it's not present in the map otherwise, it'll merge the existing value with `1` producing a sum. Method reference `Integer::sum` is an equivalent of lambda `(val1, val2) -> val1 + val2;`.

```
    public static Map<String, Integer> getAtoms(String formula) {
        Map<String, Integer> elements = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        String[] elementsAndIndices = 
                formula.split("(?<=\\p{Lower})(?=\\p{Upper})|(?<=\\p{Upper})(?=\\p{Upper})|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)");

        for (int i = 0; i < elementsAndIndices.length; i++) {
            if (elementsAndIndices[i].matches("\\p{Alpha}+")) {
                if (i == elementsAndIndices.length - 1 || !elementsAndIndices[i + 1].matches("\\d+")) {
                    elements.merge(elementsAndIndices[i], 1, Integer::sum);
                } else {
                    elements.merge(elementsAndIndices[i], Integer.parseInt(elementsAndIndices[i + 1]), Integer::sum);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
        return elements;
    }
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getAtoms("C6H12O6"));
        System.out.println(getAtoms("NH3"));
        System.out.println(getAtoms("RuSH2112"));
    }
```

**output**

```
{C=6, H=12, O=6}
{N=1, H=3}
{Ru=1, S=1, H=2112}
```